# I have a trouble when trying to initialize a function in struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, undefined-reference

I'm trying to initialize `Date`, maybe I forgot something about it. I follow **Bjarne Stroustrup**'s book but cannot run this code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    int y, m, d;               // year, month, day
    Date(int y, int m, int d); // check for valid & initialize
    void add_day(int n);       // increase the Date by n days
};

int main()
{
    Date today(2021, 1, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error which I don't know how to fix it probably:

```
undefined reference to `Date::Date(int, int, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You have *declared* what the `Date` struct looks like, but where are the *definitions* (ie, the *implementations*) of its methods? The linker can't find them (because you didn't write code for them, or didn't add that code to the project), that is what the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C++ programming language, you can define a struct just like you define a class. The reason you're getting the error is because you haven't defined the methods strictly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    /* fields */
    int _year, _month, _day;
    
    /* constructor */
    Date(int year, int month, int day) : _year(year), _month(month), _day(day){}
    
    /* setter method */
    void add_day(int n)
    {
        /* You need to develop an algorithm to keep track of the end of the month and the year. */
        _day += n;
    }
    
    /* getter method */
    int get_day()
    {
        return _day;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Date today(2021, 1, 6);
    today.add_day(1);
    cout << today.get_day() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```